# Passing arrays as reference arguments in function

Tags: c++, arrays, arguments

I am trying to pass two multidimensional arrays as reference arguments to a function in C++.

The prototype is written like this:

```
void func(char (&foo)[4][4], char (&bar)[4][4]);
```

My problem is that the second argument does not get passed as a reference argument, but the first one does. If I change their placement – so (&foo)[4][4] is second and vice versa – foo does not get passed as a reference but bar does.

However if I add a third argument, the second argument gets passed as reference.

How can I fix this without having to add another useless argument?

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not get passed as a reference"?

Comment: Show your calling code. I'm pretty sure the error's there.

Comment: What else does it get passed as ? Copy ? No way in c++. C++ passes arrays as reference even if you think you're passing a copy.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth The function cannot access and change its' values outside the function.

Comment: Please post some actual code that demonstrates the problem (see http://sscce.org).

Comment: Post the whole related thing and show what you can't change. I am pretty sure that function is able to change it's callers memory.

Answer (score 3):

Try to minimize the size of the proverbial foot to shot yourself into by using typedefs:

```
typedef char charray44[4][4];

void foo(charray44 & one, charray44 & two);
```

This should work as expected; and if not, you should be able to set up a simple test harness to figure out where (else) in the code you are making a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

```
void foo(char (&one)[4][4], char (&two)[4][4]){
}

int main(){
    char one[4][4];
    char two[4][4];
    foo(one, two);
}
```

Compiles fine on MSVC, GCC and Clang. Your problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to Xeos solution, a perhaps better way to solve this problem would be to encapsulate the array and pass the new object by reference.

```
class matrix{
     std::vector<char> values;
     size_t x_sz, y_sz;
public:
     matrix(size_t x, size_t y) : values(x*y), x_sx(x), y_sz(y) {}

     char& get_at(size_t x, size_t y) 
     { return values[y*x_sz+x]; }

     const char& get_at(size_t x, size_t y) const
     { return values[y*x_sz+x]; }
 };
```

then you can just pass to funcs like.

```
   void f(const matrix& a);
```